# Hazelcast RetryableIOException - Packet not send to

Tags: hazelcast

Sometimes we see following warning in our logs, and we are wondering when/why this will happen?

```
2017-06-24 23:46:41.211 WARN (vert.x-eventloop-thread-14) [c.h.s.i.o.i.Invocation] - [192.111.111.11]:5701 [Secure Email Gateway] [3.6.3] While asking 'is-executing': Invocation{serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', op=com.hazelcast.map.impl.operation.GetOperation{identityHash=1278259701, serviceName='hz:impl:mapService', partitionId=198, replicaIndex=0, callId=15947777, invocationTime=1498362385195 (Sat Jun 24 23:46:25 EDT 2017), waitTimeout=-1, callTimeout=8000, name=redirect.mapping.cache.info.for.451, name=redirect.mapping.cache.info.for.451}, partitionId=198, replicaIndex=0, tryCount=250, tryPauseMillis=500, invokeCount=1, callTimeout=8000, target=Address[192.111.111.11]:5701, backupsExpected=0, backupsCompleted=0, connection=null}
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.hazelcast.spi.exception.RetryableIOException: Packet not send to -> Address[192.111.111.11]:5701
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.resolveApplicationResponseOrThrowException(InvocationFuture.java:360)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:225)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.IsStillRunningService.isOperationExecuting(IsStillRunningService.java:85)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.waitForResponse(InvocationFuture.java:275)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:224)
    at com.hazelcast.spi.impl.operationservice.impl.InvocationFuture.get(InvocationFuture.java:204)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.invokeOperation(MapProxySupport.java:320)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxySupport.getInternal(MapProxySupport.java:250)
    at com.hazelcast.map.impl.proxy.MapProxyImpl.get(MapProxyImpl.java:94)
    at com.whatever.cache.provider.impl.HazelcastCacheProvider.getFromCache(HazelcastCacheProvider.java:112)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connection problem, possibly due to a network error but it will be retried (`RetryableIOException`), hence it's in WARNING level logs. Maybe you can share more logs if the problem is persistent.

Comment: That's what I though. It's not persistent - seems like we are fine then.